# Binding com PHP e PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

Bom pessoal, estou com um problema ao fazer um insert no banco de dados postgreSQL, esse é o meu insert:

```
INSERT INTO dynfipemarca (codigomarca,marca,tipo, OID, fgenabled, fgsystem , nrversion) VALUES 
                               (:codigomarca,'" . pg_escape_string(utf8_encode($nomeMarca)) . "',:tipo, '" . $codigoMarca . "' , 1 , 0, 0)
```

recebo os dados do back end de uma API, e insiro dinamicamente, aqui está meu Binding:

```
$cadastrarMarca     = conectar()->prepare($sql);
        $cadastrarMarca->bindValue(":codigomarca",$codigoMarca,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $cadastrarMarca->bindValue(":marca", $nomeMarca);
        $cadastrarMarca->bindValue(":tipo",$tipo);
        $cadastrarMarca->execute();
```

e o erro que está me aparecendo é esse

> PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::bindValue(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: :marca

eu identifiquei onde está o erro, $cadastrarMarca->bindValue(":marca", $nomeMarca); porém não sei como resolver, alguma dica?

Comment: Onde está o parâmetro `:marca` no SQL?

Comment: é que na realidade no insert onde insiro o value da marca, eu estava fazendo com :marca, porém começou a dar erro ao inserir uma marca com acento, aí eu troquei e coloquei a função pg_escape_string e utf8_encode, como tá ali no exemplo. Aí dá o erro nesse parâmetro, tem como eu fazer o encoding direto no parâmetro?

Comment: Nesse SQL: `INSERT INTO dynfipemarca (codigomarca,marca,tipo, OID, fgenabled, fgsystem , nrversion) VALUES (:codigomarca,'" . pg_escape_string(utf8_encode($nomeMarca)) . "',:tipo, '" . $codigoMarca . "' , 1 , 0, 0)` tem o parâmetro `:tipo` e o parâmetro `:codigomarca`, porque não coloca o `:marca` também já que está fazendo o *bind* dele?

Comment: como eu expliquei, começou dar erro ao inserir marcas que tem acento, entende? aí eu tirei o parametro, e exibi o que vem do back end dentro das funções de encoding

Comment: Então porque fazer o *bind* de uma parâmetro que você removeu? Retire a linha: `$cadastrarMarca->bindValue(":marca", $nomeMarca);`

Comment: hummm beleza Laércio, no caso como eu estou inserindo o que vem do back end e já está definido o valor não precisa de bind, entendi. Removi e deu certo, obrigado.

Comment: Você tentou manter o parâmetro `:marca` e deixar o SQL como `INSERT INTO dynfipemarca (codigomarca,marca,tipo, OID, fgenabled, fgsystem , nrversion) VALUES (:codigomarca,'" . pg_escape_string(utf8_encode(:marca)) . "',:tipo, '" . $codigoMarca . "' , 1 , 0, 0)`? Dessa forma poderia manter o *`bind`*.

Comment: sim tentei, mas parou de inserir as marcas, depois eu faço outro teste e vejo melhor o que acontece

Comment: Setinha pra cima na resposta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está sendo apresentado porque o parâmetro `:marca` não está no seu SQL.

Você pode remover a linha abaixo que vai resolver o problema.

```
$cadastrarMarca->bindValue(":marca", $nomeMarca);
```